# Typescript function union type lacks a call signature

Tags: javascript, typescript, union, overloading

```
interface F1 {
  (a, b): any;
}

interface F2 {
  (a): any;
}

type F3 = F1 | F2;

const f: F3 = (a) => {
  console.log(123, a);
}

f(1) // Error
```

I'm stumbled upon one of the mysterious problems in TypeScript (3.1.4). While I call `f()`, the compiler says `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'F3' has no compatible call signatures. [2349]`.

This is even strange since all of the above code works fine until that `f(1)`.

Am I missing something here? If any, how can I give the union typed function typing?

I know I can do something like this

```
interface T {
  (a, b): any;
  (a): any;
}
```

But then I have to define function in such a way

```
function (a, b?) {

}
```

which I don't like that much. Any help/feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In typescript the `|` operator describes a [union type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#34-union-types):

> A union type describes a value that can be one of several types. We use the vertical bar (|) to separate each type, so number | string | boolean is the type of a value that can be a number, a string, or a boolean.

```
interface F1 {
  (a, b): any;
}

interface F2 {
  (a): any;
}

type F3 = F1 | F2;
const f: F3 = (a) => {
  console.log(123, a);
}

const isF2 = (a): a is F2 => true; // Typeguard
if (isF2(f)) { 
  f(1); // OK
}
```

What you are looking for is the `&` operator, or the [intersection type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#35-intersection-types):

> Intersection types represent values that simultaneously have multiple types. A value of an intersection type A & B is a value that is both of type A and type B.

```
interface F1 {
  (a, b): any;
}

interface F2 {
  (a): any;
}

type F4 = F1 & F2;
const g: F4 = (a) => {
  console.log(123, a);
}

g(1); // OK
```

You can play around with these examples in this [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20F1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(a%2C%20b)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20F2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(a)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20F3%20%3D%20F1%20%7C%20F2%3B%0D%0Aconst%20f%3A%20F3%20%3D%20(a)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(123%2C%20a)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20F4%20%3D%20F1%20%26%20F2%3B%0D%0Aconst%20g%3A%20F4%20%3D%20(a)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(123%2C%20a)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ag(1)%3B%20%2F%2F%20OK%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20isF2%20%3D%20(a)%3A%20a%20is%20F2%20%3D%3E%20true%3B%0D%0Aif%20(isF2(f))%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20f(1)%3B%0D%0A%7D%20)